# spring boot : How to set spring properties dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

There are so many properties which can be defined in application.properties of spring boot application.

But I want to pass properties to configure ssl to spring from inside the code.

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
# The format used for the keystore 
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=keys/keystore.jks
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
```

So as these will be spring defined properties to be used from application.properties. I just want to set them from the code based on some logic.

For non spring application, I still have some idea that they can be passed as application, session or context properties but I am not aware on how this works in spring.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you know the properties to enable SSL in the spring boot app. You can pass these properties programmatically in your spring boot application like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

//      SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTestApplication.class, args);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("server.ssl.key-store", "/home/ajit-soman/Desktop/test/keystore.p12");
        props.put("server.ssl.key-store-password", "123456");
        props.put("server.ssl.key-store-type", "PKCS12");
        props.put("server.ssl.key-alias", "tomcat");

        new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringBootTestApplication.class)
            .properties(props).run(args);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have commented out this:
`SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTestApplication.class, args);`
and used `SpringApplicationBuilder` class to add properties to the app.

Now, these properties are defined in the program, You can apply condition and change property values based on your requirements.

Comment: will this still consider the other properties which I have defined in application.properties?

Comment: Yes . It will consider your other properties that you have added in properties files.

Comment: where does the `Properties` class come from?

Comment: @BenCreasy `java.util` has Properties class

Comment: The downside of this approach is, that the properties are set as default ones. That means, that they have the lowest precedence and every same property set in another way, eg via profile files, will overwrite the defaults. I think, something concerning security stuff should not rely on that - but that's just an opinion.

Answer (score 11):

In Spring Boot, you can read and edit propeties using `System.getProperty(String key)` and `System.setProperty(String key, String value)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // set properties
    System.setProperty("server.ssl.enabled", "true");
    System.setProperty("server.ssl.key-store-type", "PKCS12");
    System.setProperty("server.ssl.key-store", "keys/keystore.jks");
    System.setProperty("server.ssl.key-store-password", "changeit");
    System.setProperty("server.ssl.key-alias", "tomcat");

    // run
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
```

**Note**:

This will overwrite the static properties (not all but the overwritten ones).

Comment: work 100%  !! and simple without modify the xxxxxxAplication runner class of spring boot

Comment: @TienDoNam, it's not clear to me what you meant with the last line: "This will overwrite the static properties (not all but the overwritten ones)". You mean that properties set in Java will overwrite properties from `application.properties`, or the other way around?

Comment: After trial and error, I can assure that the values defined via `System.setProperty` takes precedence over the values in `application.properties` files

Answer (score 7):

You need to define and register an ApplicationListener like this:

```
public class DynamicPropertiesListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getEnvironment();
    // modify the properties here, see the ConfigurableEnvironment javadoc
  }
}
```

Now register the listener. If you run the application with the `main` method:

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(primarySources);
app.addListeners(new DynamicPropertiesListener());
app.run(args);
```

or, even better, create `src\main\resources\META-INF\spring.factories` file with this content:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=x.y.DynamicPropertiesListener
```

Where `x.y` is the package of your listener.

Comment: Using this approach was the best solution for me. Also, properties defined this way takes precedence over `application.properties' file values, and that was what I needing

Answer (score 2):

To add another option, there's a [BeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) class that you can implement. It provides two methods:

`postProcessAfterInitialization` and `postProcessBeforeInitialization`

> Factory hook that allows for custom modification of new bean instances — for example, checking for marker interfaces or wrapping beans with proxies.
> Typically, post-processors that populate beans via marker interfaces or the like will implement postProcessBeforeInitialization(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String), while post-processors that wrap beans with proxies will normally implement postProcessAfterInitialization(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String).

I was using Spring Boot with Spring Kafka and I only wanted a change for local profile.

In my code example, I was using it to override Kafka Location properties, because for SSL it doesn't read from classpath.

So this was the code:

```
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClientConfig;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.SslConfigs;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConfiguration implements BeanPostProcessor {

  @Value("${spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location:}")
  private Resource keyStoreResource;
  @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location:}")
  private Resource trustStoreResource;
  private final Environment environment;

  @SneakyThrows
  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof KafkaProperties) {
      KafkaProperties kafkaProperties = (KafkaProperties) bean;
      if(isLocalProfileActive()) {
        configureStoreLocation(kafkaProperties);
      }
    }
    return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessAfterInitialization(bean, beanName);
  }

  private boolean isLocalProfileActive() {
    return Arrays.stream(environment.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch(profile -> "local".equals(profile));
  }

  private void configureStoreLocation(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) throws IOException {
    kafkaProperties.getSsl().setKeyStoreLocation(new FileSystemResource(keyStoreResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath()));
    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(SchemaRegistryClientConfig.CLIENT_NAMESPACE + SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, keyStoreResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
    kafkaProperties.getSsl().setTrustStoreLocation(new FileSystemResource(trustStoreResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath()));
    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(SchemaRegistryClientConfig.CLIENT_NAMESPACE + SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, trustStoreResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
  }

}
```

This way I could have on my properties file:

`spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=classpath:mykeystore.jks`

And the code would get the absolute path from that and set it. It makes also possible to filter based on profiles.

It's important to mention that BeanPostProcessor runs for **EVERY** bean, so make sure you filter what you want.