# Access java variable in application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to set value from java class to application.properties

For Example

```java
// Constants.java
public interface Constants {
    String APP_NAME = "demo_app";
}
```

```
# application.properties
app.name=${Constants.APP_NAME}
```

obviously above example of application.properties will not work. But I want to access a constant variable's value from java class into application.properties.

Comment: I believe this answers your question (Implying you are not trying to write to the application.properties file): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461061/spring-boot-how-to-set-spring-properties-dynamically

Comment: @JettoMartínez No, That doesn't answer my question, I want to refer variable from java class.

Comment: Why do you need something like that? It seems impossible.

Comment: @AjeetShah I am getting properties from configuration server. And I want to use same string in my static code as constant variable.